# Disable the Cancel Button in Progress Bar in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, java-8

I have made a progress bar in javafx. There is a cancel `Button` by default. I just want to disable this cancel button when my task got completed.

```
jobProgressView.setGraphicFactory(task -> {
    return new Button("save");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Without more code, I'm only able to make a guess. Even your added code isn't enough to know all things from your implementation.

So this solution assumes, that you have a Task that is running and showing it's progress on a Progressbar. The Task here is wrapped in a service, which can be restarted (maybe you also need this?).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CancelButtonDemo extends Application {

    Service<Integer> service = new MyService();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Button start = new Button();
        Button cancel = new Button();
        ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar(0);

        start.setText("Run Task");
        start.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            if (!(service.getState().equals(Worker.State.READY))) {
                service.reset();
            }
            progress.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());
            service.start();
        });
        start.disableProperty().bind(service.runningProperty());

        cancel.setText("Cancel Task");
        cancel.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            service.cancel();
            progress.progressProperty().unbind();
            progress.setProgress(0);
        });
        cancel.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.not(service.runningProperty()));

        VBox root = new VBox(20);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().addAll(start, progress, cancel);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Cancel Button Demo");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class MyService extends Service<Integer> {

        @Override
        protected Task<Integer> createTask() {
            return new Task<Integer>() {

                @Override
                protected Integer call() throws Exception {
                    int iterations;
                    for (iterations = 0; iterations < 10000000; iterations++) {
                        if (isCancelled()) {
                            updateMessage("Cancelled");
                            break;
                        }
                        updateMessage("Iteration " + iterations);
                        updateProgress(iterations, 10000000);
                    }
                    return iterations;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The above application looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I've udpated my answer.

Comment: you have made these buttons.But in mine cancel button is by default.So it is a little bit difficult to disable that.

Comment: @GauravAgrawal I can't see it in your added code? The best is, you add a [mcve].